# How can I find out what changes have been made via a terraform apply from CloudTrail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm reviewing a problem in AWS configuration, which is managed via Terraform. I would like to find out if a specific change was made via a local `tf apply` and by whom.

In CloudTrail, I can see events like `ModifyReplicationGroup`, but I can't see any detail of what was changed.

Is it possible to find out what variables were actually modified in that event?